# Collect data with google analytics and send to your server

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics

It's possible use google analytics for iOS / Android to collect data and send it twice to Analytics server and a Custom Server implementation?
Where i can configure this behavior for example in iOS [sdk](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/) app?

Comment: No idea if you can do it natively, but at least segment.com (and possibly other similar services) support sending data to multiple destinations via their SDK, including http APIs that would support custom integrations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but it isn't possible to get Google Analytics to send its hit data anywhere other than to Google Analytics.

Comment: you understand the problem. It's not possible?

Comment: Nope. Allowing you to send the data elsewhere would potentially lead to legal problems for them, as well as giving away too much about how their systems work, and allowing other people to swoop in and steal their business.